# How can I create a NuGet package for Windows Phone 8.1 from a PCL project?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nuget

My PCL project is setup with these targets:

1. .NET Framework 4
2. Silverlight 5
3. Windows 8
4. Windows Phone 8.1
5. Windows Phone Silverlight 8

I created the PCL target for my nuspec file using the [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/).

My target looks like this: `lib\portable-net4+sl5+wp8+win8`.

If I create a Windows 8 test project, I can find the latest version of my library in NuGet. If I create a Windows Phone 8.1 project, this version does not show up.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to NuGet documentation (please take a look [here](https://docs.nuget.org/create/enforced-package-conventions) at "Common Framework and Profile Targeting Examples" section) you need to add `wpa` to your target to make it work. Please be also aware that `wpa` target works only with NuGet 2.8.1+

Those same profile targets are what is used for the items in the portable profile target.

Comment: I'm doing a PCL build though, so it should be something similar to the `portal-` ones just below that.

Comment: So, apparently those same profiles can be used for the portable profile too, so this worked. I'll update your answer to include that information, and mark it as the solution.